# Regex having "." (no other special characters) between text it can have many dots with text around but not two dots consecutively "example.one.three"

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

so I am looking for a regex which disallows two consecutive "." but it can have many. Also the string should not start or end with ".".

I've written a regex but it allows multiple dots consecutively.

```
new RegExp("^[0-9a-z].*[0-9a-z]$", "i"),
```

**valid examples**

```
"abc.def.hun.asasdsd"
"asasaasass.l"
"p.asasasas"
```

**invalid examples**

```
".asassa"
"sasas..sasas.sas"
"asas.sasas.sasas."
"sasas...sasasdsd.sasass"
```

Comment: @Sheraz: Your sample only show alphanumeric characters except `.` but your comments mention other special characters. Is `ab.foo # bar@123` valid?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command, to start with `^[0-9a-z]` with the number of letters, and then groups of dot with letters and numbers but not two sequential dots.

```js
const result = new RegExp("^[0-9a-z]+?(\.[0-9a-z]+)*$", "i").test('one.dsfsdf.');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: this is working for every special character but i only need for "."

Comment: No, it doesn't accept special characters

Comment: it is excepting it treating every special character as "."

Comment: ts_name: yup.string().required("Required*").matches(
    new RegExp("^[0-9a-z]+?(.[0-9a-z]+)*$", "i"),
    'This field should be alphanumeric with "." in between '
  ),

Comment: My regular expression pass all cases you mentioned in the post. https://regex101.com/r/Go53if/1

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```bash
/^[a-z\d](?!.*\.\.)(?:.*[a-z\d])?$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KJ9Z8Z/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^[a-z\d]`: Match alphanumeric char at start
- `(?!.*\.\.)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if 2 consecutive dots are present anywhere
- `(?:.*[a-z\d])?`: Match anything followed by alphanumeric char. Make this an optional group match
- `$`: End

Comment: but i also want no other special characters than "." how can i acheive that?

Comment: Then what's wrong with: `/^[\da-z]+(?:\.[\da-z]+)*$/gmi` ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this works for your case?

`^[0-9a-z]+(\.[0-9a-z]+)*$`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mbYWsm/2)

Comment: this is working for every special character but i only need for "."

Comment: What is an example of such a special character that gets matched with this regex?

Comment: like the string will be alphanumeric with the exception of "." and the conditions it cannot be at start nor at end and also not two consecutively.